# Chromium browser not loading youtube video

Tags: chromium, youtube

I am using Ubuntu and have chromium installed in it. For every video on you tube it is giving me an error that the video is not available. I had installed flash player too but it is not working. I don't know why it is happening.

On clicking to learn more link, the help is answering like the video is removed or currently unavailable which is not possible as it could not be the case for every video on you tube.